# How to reset a jquery multiselect checkbox dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I have the below code. As per the functionality, When the user chooses the first radio button, no action is required but when the user chooses the second radio button, a multiselect jquery dropdown is shown up. User can select the checkboxes. This is fine. After the user checks the checkboxes and then click on the first radio button, the dropdown should get disappear and the values should get reset or in other words, checkboxes should get unchecked. I am able to make it disappear using `hide()`, but the values are not getting unchecked. So when I come back, I still see the old values.

```
<div id="radioButton" data-role="fieldcontain" style="display: none">
    <label for="flip-1">Choose Something </label>
       <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">

         <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" /> 
         <label for="radio-choice-1">All Business Catergories</label> 
         <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2" /> 
         <label for="radio-choice-2">A specific business category</label>

       </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="multiCheckbox" style="display: none">

    <select name="busiUnit" id="day" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
        <option>Business Unit Category</option>
        <option value="29">ABC</option>
        <option value="30">XYZ</option>
        <option value="31">BCD</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

I am using the jquery `hide()` & `show()` methods, for displaying and hiding the dropdown. Below code for 
for reading the checkboxes.

```
$("#day").change(function(){

    var str = "";
    busiArray=[];                                

    $( "select#day option:selected" ).each(function() {

        str = $( this ).val();
        busiArray.push(str);

    });

});
```

How do I reset the dropdown ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to `change` event to any radio button you want, and then reset *value* `.val("")` of the selectmenu followed by `.selectmenu("refresh")` to re-apply styles.

Note that you need to use jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 as there was a [bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7732) in previous versions.

```
$("#radio-choice-1").on("change", function () {
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $("#day").val("").selectmenu("refresh");
   }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vopxz743/)**

Answer (score -1):

Try this code to reset the dropdown:

```js
var items = ["facebook","twitter","instagram","stackoverflow"];

    // Populate dropdown
   jQuery.each(items,function(i,d){
           // auto select option
           jQuery("#populate").append("<option "+(i==3?"selected":"")+">"+d+"</option>");
   });
   // Reset 
   jQuery("input[class=reset]").click(function(){
     
          jQuery("#populate option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="populate">
  <option>--</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Reset" class="reset"/>
```